# Alternative to using temp table/temp variables or CTE inside a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

I have a scenario where I have to create a view which has a bunch of UNIONS of various select statements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ID,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(FIRST_NAME,'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown' AS label,
ISNULL(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
  FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
  UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(EMP_ID,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(LAST_NAME,'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown' AS label,
ISNULL(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
  FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
  UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(LICENSE,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(COMPANY,'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown' AS label,
ISNULL(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
  FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
.
.
.
.
.
10 such selects
```

I try using temporary variable & temp tables to avoid making 10 different calls to the database but looks like they do not work inside a view like below.

```
Create View [test].[emp].[MainView]
AS
select * into #tempTable from [test].[emp].[OrgView]
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ID,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(FIRST_NAME,'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown' AS label,
ISNULL(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
  FROM #tempTable
  UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(EMP_ID,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(LAST_NAME,'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown' AS label,
ISNULL(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
  FROM #tempTable
  UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(LICENSE,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(COMPANY,'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown' AS label,
ISNULL(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
  FROM #tempTable
```

Cannot use common table expression(CTE) as well with above query as it will be available to  just one lookup and not to the rest 9.

What is the better way of doing it in Sql Server ?

Comment: If you put a lot of UNIONs in your view it will still be only one call to the database.  The database engine will figure out the best exeuction plan for you.  But why do you ask? Sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: Correct - a view consists of a single sql statement. If you scale your example down and post a repro script / fiddle and provide the desired result from your sample data, someone might provide useful suggestions. I hope you do understand the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`.

Comment: There seems to be little value in adding `'ID', 'unknown:Unknown', 'unknown'` to the result set for rows where values are missing. This just makes the engine work harder -- consider excluding those values in a `WHERE` (eliminating the `ISNULL`s) and adding them back with new queries if necessary (i.e. invert the `WHERE`s). The optimizer can recognize when subqueries have conditions that logically exclude each other, but it can't optimize `DISTINCT` over expressions. This would likely also allow you to use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `CROSS APPLY` instead of `UNION`.  I am a little unclear on where you want to put the logic, but here is the idea:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.Id, 
       (COALESCE(FIRST_NAME, 'unknown') + ':' + 'Unknown') AS label,
       COALESCE(VALUE,'unknown') AS [value]
FROM #tempTable CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (COALESCE(ID, 'ID')),
             (COALESCE(EMP_ID, 'ID')),
             (COALESCE(LICENCE_ID, 'ID')),
             . . .
     ) v(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you you use a `VIEW`, it's a 1 call to the database regardless of what's inside the view. So there is no need to use temp tables or table variables etc. So, your original query would work just fine inside a `VIEW` and it would be a single SQL call.

```
CREATE VIEW [test].[emp].[MainView]
AS
SELECT .... FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
UNION
SELECT .... FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
....
```

It's efficiency is another matter and I can't comment on that as the complete logic is not posted in your questions. However, if all `JOIN`s and `WHERE` clauses in all `SELECT` statements are similar/compatible with each other, then you could combine them with a `CROSS APPLY` as @gordon-linoff suggested but I see you're mentioning one of the queries is using a lookup not shared by other queries so that may or may not be possible (your post is missing the details).